# Ошибка .\os.go:18:31: cannot use cur (type *user.User) as type string in argument to f.WriteString

Tags: файлы, golang

Мне нужно узнать `User` и записать в текстовый файл, как мне конвертировать в тип `string`?

Код:

```
package main

import "os"
import "os/user"

func main(){
    f, err := os.OpenFile("test.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    cur, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {

    } else {

        if _, err = f.WriteString(cur); err != nil {
        panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
# command-line-arguments
.\os.go:18:31: cannot use cur (type *user.User) as type string in argument to f.WriteString
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сериализировать объект. К примеру, в json. 
https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/example_test.go

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно просто записать имя юзера, используйте поле [`Username`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/#User.Username):

```
if _, err = f.WriteString(cur.Username); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Если же вам нужна вся доступная информация, смотрите ответ коллеги и сериализуйте юзера.